# Is there a function which can show the "script run" statistic of the simulator

Tags: linden-scripting-language

Recent simulator server versions appear to be preferring stable time dilation and fps over script service. On many occasions I have seen sims operating at 10% to 15% script run while maintaining 45 sim fps. It used to be that testing the FPS or dilation was a reasonable indicator of when to drop my scripts into low accuracy states but this is no longer the case. Is there a way to read the script run % of the simulator from LSL? (the same stat shown in ctrl+shift+1)

Comment: There is no simple function to access those values easily. You would need to build your own profiling function within your LSL code. The script profiler functions seem like a good starting point.